# How to harvest whole walnuts of a tall tree in one day?

Tags: harvesting, walnut

[image]

This picture show a walnut harvest machine. But I think this machine is useful for walnut trees that are around 10 meters height. I don't know which kind of machine is appropriate for trees around 30 meters height. people do this using some kind of elevators? Please help me to know how to harvest a tall walnut tree, using a machine or in other quick ways .

Comment: do you have a picture of the tree you want to harvest?

Comment: Ok first, I have to ask why? If you are going commercial or sideline, then I can see a reason, but if not then you are wasting money, because as a hobbyist, even one who wants to harvest a few barrel fills will usually just wait until the nuts hit the ground, the. You pick them up by hand and put them in your tractor wagon.

Comment: See here for some ideas for manual collection: http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/2320/22

Comment: Heh, definitely beyond DIY and home gardening if you need a tree shaker. I've always found time, gravity, a rake and a flat loading shovel to be highly efficient. The miserable part is hulling (not shelling).

Comment: Here we have almost 1000 tall walnut trees. Until now people were harvesting these trees trough climbing and using long woods. Once a man fall of tree and died. I just like to introduce them some better ways.

Comment: I expect a good answer that introduce me some new ways or machines that help me to harvest whole the walnuts of a tall tree in one day.

Comment: I just tried googling "squirrel walnut harvesting" and even "drone walnut harvesting", but to now avail :) Nice question too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about harvesting walnuts on an agricultural scale. Please see [help/on-topic] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

May be you are looking for some thing like this. there are various types of garden elevators that you can use them, even they are not to fast in great gardens.
two more idea:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

In a home garden, the best way to harvest is to wait until the nuts fall naturally. It can be a regular chore before mowing, at the end of the season, to run out with a [roller harvester](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FNK8K4) and a 5 gallon bucket, and pick up all the nuts that had fallen in the last week.

This method is also cool, because you can process them over an extended period, and don't have to wear yourself out trying to get it all done in one fell swoop.

The biggest problem with this method is squirrels, but they're a problem with almost every nut growing program.

Answer (score 3):

Walnuts are mechanically harvested by machinery which literally just locates onto the trunk and shakes the tree, making the nuts fall to the ground. Other additions to the machine, or a separate machine, can be used to collect them up, or they can simply be raked up by hand, though many may have a brush or air system to push the nuts into piles; these are then collected separately by a large harvesting machine. Most of the machines for 'shaking' have a hydraulic arm which can be raised and lowered, depending on the height of the tree, so that it can be 'clamped' in the appropriate place on the trunk.

I can't see properly in your photograph, but its likely that arm sticking out and clamping the tree is, indeed, hydraulic and can be raised and lowered. It also looks as if that machine has some sort of brush collection system, or at least a method of creating piles for collection, judging by the brushes fitted on the bottom.

I'd guess you need to locate a mechanical harvesting equipment hire or sales company in your area and see what they've got available. Even so, 1000 trees in one day, not sure if that's possible, even with the right bit of kit, something you need to ask the machinery company.

Comment: Thank you. I meant whole walnuts of a tree in one day  and not whole walnut trees in one day :-)

Comment: Ah! Well it makes no difference to the rest of the answer anyway...